# How can use global let declaration in ES6?

Tags: javascript, variables

How I can use ES6 global `let` declaration?

```
let video = document.getElementById("video");
let button = document.getElementById("controllbutton");
```

The Above code causes Error that `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement` on Firefox.

Why above code causes Syntax Error?

Comment: Can it be syntax error above these teo lines? These seem syntaxically correct.

Comment: You need to use `type="application/javascript;version=1.7"` for the script tag ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)). What is the idea behind using a "global block scope"?

Answer (score 1):

Are you transpiling?  I don't see browser support for FF for this feature:
https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Answer (score 1):

I added `type="application/javascript;version=1.7"` in script tag, it resolved Syntax Error.